# fgets cannot read correctly when there is no new line at the end of file

Tags: c, file

The problem is that fgets displays wrong if there is no new line at the end of file. Assume if I have 2 text files as follow,

**content of text1.txt:**

```
German Hoy
43
68
Jesse Boster
88
29
```

- note that file ends completely after 29. no line after 29.

**content of text2.txt:**

```
German Hoy
43
68
Jesse Boster
88
29
```

- note that there is one more line after 29.

**My Problem:**

the program runs correct for text2.txt when there is one more line after the end of the file. However, it doesn't if I do not have one more line at the end of the file like text1.txt. How can I fix this? I want to have same result regardless of having or not having one more line at the end of the file. (In both case it should output same result)

**Below is part of source code related to problem:**

```
while( fgets (s, 60, file)!=NULL )  {
        s[strlen(s)-1] = '\0';
        strcpy(tempName, s);

        fgets(s, 60, file);
        s[strlen(s)-1] = '\0';
        sscanf(s, "%d", &tempMid);

        fgets(s, 60, file);
        s[strlen(s)-1] = '\0';
        sscanf(s, "%d", &tempFinal);

        setup(tempName, tempMid, tempFinal);
    }
```

**System used is LINUX**

Comment: What output do you get?  You should be checking each of the `fgets()` calls to ensure that you didn't get an EOF report.  You should be showing us an MCVE ([MCVE]) — your `setup()` call, for instance, could be replaced by a suitable `printf()` call.  Also, which platform are you working on?  Windows vs Unix-like might make a difference.

Comment: `s[strlen(s)-1] = '\0';` replace with `s[strcspn(s, "\n")] = '\0';`. Also The second and third `s[strlen(s)-1] = '\0';` are unnecessary.

Comment: Thank you for the update — except that the update isn't an MCVE, and the input is wholly different from what was described previously, and the output you're getting is missing, and the output you expect isn't obvious from the input you show.  Actually, the update isn't helpful at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put extra new line at the end of the `s` buffer your self regardless

```
fgets(s, 60, file);
length = strlen(s);
s[length] = '\n';
s[length+1] = '\0';
sscanf(s, "%d", &tempFinal);
```

**IMPORTANT NOTE:**

You have to make sure that your buffer is at least 61 byte long to fit the new line.

Comment: There was already a null byte at the end; you only add one character, so you only need 61 bytes in the buffer.

Comment: You are right, I thought fgets will do similar to strcpy :)

Comment: @ameen Yeah, now fixed, Thank you veryveryvery much!

Comment: Why not just omit the 3 lines `length = strlen(s);
s[length] = '\n';
s[length+1] = '\0';`?

Comment: because the problem is when there is no newline at the end of the file

Comment: @ameen This is no functionality difference with this answer's code if the 3 lines were dropped when trying to find `tempFinal`.

Comment: @ameen just one more question. I have to change "fgets(s, 60, file);" to "fgets(s, 61, file);" , because you said my buffer is at least 61 byte long to fit?

Comment: @online.0227 no just make the buffer size 61 and leave the fgets as the are, one byte less.

Comment: @ameen oh ok so i change s[60] to s[61] but don't change fgets. thank you very much.

Comment: @chux hmm..., now I think about it, it might work, he could have been overwriting the last digit and getting the wrong result, I thought that sscanf is failing since he didn't specify what was the problem and since I never use the standard library anymore because I have my own and I don't remember the details of it. so if it doesn't work for him when there isn't a new line adding a newline will make it work for sure.

Comment: Note that `strcat(s,"\n");` would do the same as `length = strlen(s);
s[length] = '\n';
s[length+1] = '\0';`

Answer (score 3):

Strip the new line optionally:

```
while( fgets (s, 60, file)!=NULL )  {
  s[strcspn(s, "\n")] = '\0';
```

Do not use `s[strlen(s)-1] = '\0';` as it can be a hacker exploit.  `fgets()` reads a null character just like any other non-new line character.  This *first* character in a line may be a `'\0'` and then OP's code invokes undefined behavior.

Further, in OP code, the lopping off of the potential new line character is not even needed.

```
    fgets(s, 60, file);
    // s[strlen(s)-1] = '\0';
    sscanf(s, "%d", &tempMid);
```

Also it would be better to test the return value of `sccanf()` or perhaps use `strtol()`.

Answer (score 1):

This code is approximately an MCVE:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    char s[60];
    char tempName[60];
    int tempMid;
    int tempFinal;
    FILE *file = stdin;

    while (fgets(s, 60, file) != NULL)
    {
        s[strlen(s) - 1] = '\0';
        strcpy(tempName, s);

        if (fgets(s, 60, file) == NULL)
            break;
        s[strlen(s) - 1] = '\0';
        sscanf(s, "%d", &tempMid);

        if (fgets(s, 60, file) == NULL)
            break;
        s[strlen(s) - 1] = '\0';
        sscanf(s, "%d", &tempFinal);

        printf("[%s] %d %d\n", tempName, tempMid, tempFinal);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

It takes the fragment you wrote, wraps it in `main()` with two headers, adapts it to read from standard input, and checks that the `fgets()` calls all succeed.

I called the program `fg17`.  When run on your two data files, I get:

```
$ fg17 < text1.txt
[German Hoy] 43 68
[Jesse Boster] 88 2
$ fg17 <text2.txt
[German Hoy] 43 68
[Jesse Boster] 88 29
$
```

This is what I expected since your code zaps the last character of the last line, regardless of whether it is a newline or not.  If you want the output to include the `9` of `29`, then you have to be more careful:

```
s[strcspn(s, "\n")] = '\0';
```

With that change deployed 3 times, the output is the same from both programs.

What's the difference?  `strcspn()` returns the number of characters that are not found in the string argument — or the number of characters to the null byte.  If there is no newline, it reports on the null byte, and the assignment overwrites the null byte with another null byte — a no-op.  But it is reliable and safe.